# How to install MySQL-python - CentOS

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have already installed mysql-devel, it didn't solve the problem.

I am trying to executed the following commands:

```
sudo easy_install-2.7 MySQL-python
sudo pip2.7 install  MySQL-python
```

in the first one I see:

> error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit
>   status 1

In the second one:

> Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-nySVuQ/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-eC4DGP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nySVuQ/MySQL-python/

Is there any possibility to solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try yum group install ‘Development Tools’

Comment: was trying, I see:

Comment: Warning: Group development-tools does not have any packages.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update